# Why iOS App name is capitalised even dow I set uncapitalized project name?

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a "Trade Movie Records" project in Xcode, and when I run app, it uses under icon the "Trade movie records" label, why? How can I force use small capital?

I change Bundle name to  "Trade movie records", that was the trick, thanks.

[image]

Comment: What's the value of `PRODUCT_NAME` in Settings > Build Settings > Packaging > Product Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [CFBundleDisplayName](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html) key in your Info.plist.